# Where is the error/lack of loader reference in my webpack config?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Have a fairly boilerplate webpack config that with a new project fails to bundle any of my react code.

Error reads

```
ERROR in ./index.jsx 47:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (47:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

Here's my webpack file

```
const path = require('path');
const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/src');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist');

module.exports = {
  context: SRC_DIR,
  entry: './index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: DIST_DIR
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Have a feeling there's something rather simple i'm missing, would appreciate any insight as to what the issue may be.

*Update - Including Dist Tree*

```
├── client
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── Form.jsx
│   │   │   ├── TableList.jsx
│   │   │   └── TableListItem.jsx
│   │   └── index.jsx
│   └── dist
│       ├── index.html
│       └── bundle.js
├── server
│   └── index.js
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Using the same key on a object twice will overwrite that key. Start by splitting up the rules object into different objects in the rules array.

Comment: So the two use keys im placing in the rules object may be apart of the problem?

Comment: And the two test keys. You cannot do this, the next one will overwrite the first one. The logic for the webpack config is: for each file that it has to load it will check if a test is successful. If so, use the other prop to correctly load the file. E.g: If it has to load a css file it will check for each of the objects in the rules array if a test is successful. This wil be /\.css$/ . It will then load the file with these ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] loaders. So for each file that is NOT js you need to specify a rule so webpack can load it.

Answer (score 0):

You need `babel-loader` that will transpile your `.jsx` into vanila javascript. You need to add following to you `webpack.config` file:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: didnt work for me but I appreciate the help nevertheless!

Comment: still having the same error. Updated question to include my file structure. Starting to think it's not a problem with my config persay.